# Sending UDP packets in Objective C: packet arriving without any data

Tags: objective-c, udp

I'm trying to send UDP packets in objective C. More specifically, building with xcode targeting the iphone 6.1 simulator.

I can't seem to actually receive the data I send. Weirdly, I do get a data event... the data's just been truncated to length 0.

I've cut it down as much as I can, to make a dead simple test I think should pass.

```
#import "UdpSocketTest.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CFSocket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

@implementation UdpSocketTest

static int receivedByteCount = 0;
void onReceive(CFSocketRef socket, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info);
void onReceive(CFSocketRef socket, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info) {
    // this gets called once, but CFDataGetLength(data) == 0
    receivedByteCount += CFDataGetLength(data);
}

-(void) testUdpSocket {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(5000); // <-- doesn't really matter, not sending from receiver
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr);
    CFSocketContext socketContext = { 0, (__bridge void*)self, CFRetain, CFRelease, NULL };

    // prepare receiver
    CFSocketRef receiver = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP ,kCFSocketDataCallBack, (CFSocketCallBack)onReceive, &socketContext);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, receiver, 0), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFSocketConnectToAddress(receiver, CFDataCreate(NULL, (unsigned char *)&addr, sizeof(addr)), -1);

    // point sender at receiver
    CFSocketRef sender = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, kCFSocketDataCallBack, (CFSocketCallBack)onReceive, &socketContext);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, sender, 0), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFSocketConnectToAddress(sender, CFSocketCopyAddress(receiver), -1);

    // send data of sixty zeroes, allow processing to occur
    CFSocketSendData(sender, NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)[NSMutableData dataWithLength:60], 2.0);
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];

    // did the data arrive?
    STAssertTrue(receivedByteCount > 0, @"");
    // nope
}
@end
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it's something obvious, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised you're getting any callbacks at all—you're never actually binding your receiver to your local port.  You're creating two sockets and telling both of them "I went to send data to `127.0.0.1:5000`", but nowhere are you saying "I want to receive data on `127.0.0.1:5000`.

In order to do that, you should be calling [`CFSocketSetAddress`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html) on the receiver socket, *not* `CFSocketConnectToAddress`.  This is equivalent to calling the [`bind(2)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man2/bind.2.html) system call on the underlying native BSD socket.

Comment: Bah, I assumed it was implicitly binding when I "connected" it. I knew it would be incredibly obvious but... bleh. (I started from existing code that I assumed worked. Guess it was never tested.) I'll try this tomorrow and report back.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for answering an obvious question and saving me a lot of time.

Comment: It turns out the zero-data callback was going to the *sender*. Seems to be related to the recipient not being reachable. No idea why it makes it past the 'data callbacks only' mask.